# Bash: get multiple value from text file in the same line

Tags: bash, shell

i have a text file with 2 string per line, i need make a `curl` command whith these vales

text file:

```
www.example.com 38494740
www.example.org 49347398
www.example.net 94798340
```

I need create a command `curl` for lines, eg.

```
curl www.example.com/38494740
curl www.example.org/49347398
curl www.example.net/94798340
```

I have considerate `while` but i have 2 string per line....

UPDATE:

I need use these values as variable, the command can also be this way `curl www.exmple.com/foo/38494740`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v OFS="/" '{$1=$1}1' curl
www.example.com/38494740
www.example.org/49347398
www.example.net/94798340
```

Explanation :
 `OFS` defines how your output fields would be separated. Here its set to "/".
`{$1=$1}` : is to make awk to reconstruct the records so new OFS will come into effect.
`1:` is awk's default action to print the line.

As per comments :

```
while read domain sub
do

curl "$domain"/"$sub"


done < curl
```

Comment: I need use these values as variable, the command can also be this way `curl www.exmple.com/foo/38494740`

Comment: can you update question with more clarity and details ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
while read hostname number ; do echo "curl ${hostname}/${number}" ; done < inputFile
```

Output:

```
curl www.example.com/38494740
curl www.example.org/49347398
curl www.example.net/94798340
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one foolproof way of getting it done.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r url port;     # Read the tab-spaced file for the 'url' and 'port'
do
    curl "${url}"/"${port}" # Construct the URL as "url/port" to run curl command on it
done < file
```

Comment: @PS.: Thanks for the edit, `foolproof` doesn't exist anymore? :)

Comment: still there, not sure if you mean full proof or fool proof.

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution is to just use `tr` to translate all spaces to `/`:

```
tr ' ' '/' < inputfile
```